# How can I create a PR across forks using the Azure DevOps Service API?

Tags: python, azure-devops-rest-api

I have two repos on Azure DevOps, let's call them `parent_repo` and `child_repo`. The `child_repo` is a fork of the parent. What I'd like to do is create a PR to merge `master` of `child_repo` to `master` of `parent_repo` using the Azure DevOps Services API, by way of [its Python library](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api).

According to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/572968/cannot-create-pull-request-from-fork-to-upstream-r.html), `forkSource` is the parameter needed to indicate that the source branch is in a fork, and to provide the `repo_id` of that fork.

```py
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

_connection = Connection(base_url=URL, creds=BasicAuthentication("", PAT))
CLIENT = _connection.clients.get_git_client()

args = {
    "git_pull_request_to_create": {
        "sourceRefName": f"refs/heads/master",
        "targetRefName": f"refs/heads/master",
        "forkSource": {"repository": {"repository": child_repo_id}},
        "title": "...",
        "description": "...",
    },
    "repository_id": parent_repo_id,
}

res = CLIENT.create_pull_request(**args)
```

The nested dictionary I've provided for `forkSource` is a result of trial and error with the library, and it does successfully create a PR. However, the PR this creates is to merge `parent:master` to `parent:master`, so it's not useful.

How can I change `args` so it will create a PR for `child:master` to `parent:master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I dug a little deeper into the docs, starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/gitpullrequest#forksource) with `forkSource`. Following that link into [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/gitforkref?view=azdevops-ext-latest) then [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/gitrepository?view=azdevops-ext-latest) it became apparent that `forkSource` has to be formulated like so:

`"forkSource": {"repository": {"id": child_repo_id}}`

Oddly, the DevOps API was ignoring the nested `repository` param instead of (preferably) throwing an error. This change resolves the issue and creates a PR resembling the one I'm after.

Full code:

```py
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

_connection = Connection(base_url=URL, creds=BasicAuthentication("", PAT))
CLIENT = _connection.clients.get_git_client()

args = {
    "git_pull_request_to_create": {
        "sourceRefName": f"refs/heads/master",
        "targetRefName": f"refs/heads/master",
        "forkSource": {"repository": {"id": child_repo_id}}, # the only change required
        "title": "...",
        "description": "...",
    },
    "repository_id": parent_repo_id,
}

res = CLIENT.create_pull_request(**args)
```

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT done. Maybe you could take my note about the expected error as a bug report? :-)